# we use by when something happens by a time in the future not until

Tags: prepositions

**"It's too late to go shopping. The shops are open only until 5:30. they will be closed by now."**

First: what is closed here? an adjective?

Meanwhile:

Taking the italic part into account, there has been obviously mentioned the fact that if something happens, then we use ***by***. Nevertheless, in my original question, the following phrase is just a statement not an action, so why don't we use until?

"Closed" represents a state, not an action.

........................

***EDITED:***
My biggest and most important and specific question:

My specific question, now, is about the fact that considering the following explanations, and as being closed is just a **statement** not an action, why does my original sentence use **by** rather than **until**?

The followings are extracted from the book English Grammar in Use:

> **1 until
>
>   Something *continues* until a time in the future:**
>
> > Fred will be away until Monday. (so he'll be back on Monday)
> >      I'll be working until 11.30. (so I'll stop working at 11.30)
>
> **2 by
>
>   Something *happens* by a time in the future:**
>
> > Fred will be back by Monday. (= he'll be back not later than Monday)
> >     I'll have finished my work by 11. 30. (I'll finish my work not later than 11. 30)
>
> C. You can say 'by the time something happens'. Study these examples:
>
> > It's not worth going shopping now. By the time we get to the shops,
> >     they will be closed. (= the shops will close between now and the time we get
> >     there)
>
> . . .
>
> UNIT 119 By and until, By the time...
>
> A. By (+ a time) ='not later than':
>
> - I posted the letter today, so they should receive it by Monday. (= on or before Monday, not later than Monday)
> - We'd better hurry. We have to be at home by 5 o'clock. (= at or before 5 o'clock, not later than 5 o'clock)
> - Where's Sue? She should be here by now. (= now or before now - so she should have arrived already)
>
> You cannot use until with this meaning:
>
> - Tell me by Friday whether or not you can come to the party. (not 'Tell me until Friday')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It’s too late to go shopping. The shops are open only until 5:30. They will be closed by now.

Yes, *closed* here is employed as an adjective. You are correct in understanding it to designate a state rather than an event.

And it is true that the expression *by TIME* is used with events rather than states—as your source says, it says that something ‘happens’ (an event) rather than ‘continues’ (a state).

*HOWEVER*: The expression *by TIME* does not compel you to employ an ‘eventive’ predicate or forbid you to use a ‘stative’ predicate. In fact, the compulsion works in the opposite direction: when you use *by TIME*, you compel your hearer to understand the predicate in an eventive sense. With *by TIME* the hearer interprets a stative predicate as the result of a **change of state**: something happened before *TIME* to bring about the state you describe.

Here are examples of *by TIME* with three stative verbs, *know*, *own*, *be*:

> **By April** he knew that the operation was a failure. ... *implies that he did not know this earlier, but at some time before April he **learned** that the operation was a failure*
>
> **By 1973** he owned 26 newspapers. ... *implies that he did not own so many newspapers earlier, but at some time before 1973 he **acquired** 26 newspapers*
>
> **By next week** you will be in Toronto. ... *implies that you are not in Toronto now, but at some time before next week you **will go** to Toronto*

In the same way, *The shops will be closed **by now*** implies that earlier the shops were open, but at some time before now the shops **were closed**. Since it is explicitly stated that the shops are open until 5:30, we understand that this sentence must have been uttered at some time after 5:30.

---

The word *will* may have caused you some confusion. This *will* does not designate some time in the future; it expresses a certain inference in the present. (Linguists call this ‘epistemic’ *will*.)  Your last sentence may be paraphrased

> It is **certain** that they **are** closed by now.

Comment: First thanks. But,I failed to get what this means:You appear to have been misled by the word will in They will be closed by now. This is not 'futurive' 'will', designating some time in the future, but 'epistemic', designating an inference as certain. The time reference at which that inference holds is marked as the present by the present-tense form of will and the temporal PP by now:

Comment: @nima_persian Sorry, I omitted a word. This *will* does not point to a future time but asserts that something must be true.

Comment: I've managed to understand that PP is "prepositional phrase", but failed to twig what is "the present-tense form of *will*".

Comment: @CopperKettle *will* is the present-tense **form** (not necessarily **meaning**. The past-tense form is *would* (again, not necessarily with past-tense **meaning**).

Comment: I am still too confused with my edited question.

Comment: @nima_persian Thank you for your very thorough rewrite of your question. I think I understand your problem better now, and I have rewritten my answer to address it.

Comment: As usual, your explanations are invariable  invaluable. Many thanks.

Comment: Could anyone tell me how I could send my private English question to members of this site?

Comment: @nima_persian You might ask on Chat